# Why do Scala immutable HashMap methods return a Map?

Tags: scala, hashmap, immutability

I am having problems using the update method of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.I don't see the reason it returns a Map instead of a HashMap. How do I get a new HashMap with a new key-value pair added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the expected behavior. `HashMap` is most useful as a specific implementation of `Map` involving using a hash table for lookups.

Usually, you'd say `var values: Map[String, Any] = new HashMap`, and then sit back and use it as if it's a plain ol' immutable `Map`.

Do you have a reason for your code to know that it's a HashMap after you've `new`'d it as above?

Answer (score 7):

If you're using 2.7 this is because over time the collections library has become inconsistent with various implementation class not specializing the return types of some methods.  This is one of the things that is fixed in the collections library redesign for 2.8.

If you're using 2.8, this is because the `update` method is deprecated and you should use `updated` instead. This correctly specializes the return value.

```
scala> HashMap(1->1, 2->2, 3->3, 4->4).updated(1,3)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map((2,2), (4,4), (1,3), (3,3))
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2.7.x, it returns a `Map` because it might be a `ListMap` or `TreeMap` or whatever, and it was deemed to be too much work to redefine the methods each time.

In 2.8.x, it should return a `HashMap`--but you have to use `updated` (`update` is deprecated).